# Can a hacker simply copy shared prefs from one device to another to hijack a user session/state?

Tags: android, security

I need to test a scenario in which a hacker will try to copy the shared prefs file (or files) from one Android device to another in order to have the same state that the original user has and use the app as if he is the original user (hijack his existing sessions for instance).

I tried to copy the shared prefs file from one device to another (where I had installed a fresh copy of the app with an empty shared prefs file). Copied the file from the original device using adb , copied it to the sd card of the target device and move it to the right shared prefs directory using a file management app with root privileges. This didn't work.

When I start the app on the target device - I can see that the shred prefs file get "rolled-back" to its initial form. Maybe Android has some kin of mechanism to prevent manipulation of an app's files/data.

So my question is - how can I test this scenario in other ways? any way to transfer the shares prefs from one device to another without Android knowing about it?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't store anything in shared preferences that will allow a hacker to hijack another user's session. There isn't really a way to protect against this because all the hacker needs in order to access these files is a rooted device.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
The app is already in Google play and Iv'e already started planning to change how the info is stored but for now - I have to check for any possible vulnerabilities. This is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Android **does not** have any kind of mechanism to prevent manipulation of an app's files/data.
**But some application does.**
A lot methods can be used to check if the shared prefs file is copied from another device, like device ID/IMEI compare,etc.

Other ways can do this kind of test:

1. `adb backup` & `adb restore` commands.
2. any another backup&restore function provided by your device or google.